# How to apt install from a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to make a script to setup a new VM to be ready for use, which involves some installs, but when I put the install commands (`apt-get --yes install <package>`) in the a script they always fail with:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

The script is run as root (`sudo ./setup.sh`)

When I check for `apt` process I get:

```
4 S root      2227     1  0  80   0 -  1126 -      07:33 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update

0 S root      2231  2227  0  80   0 -  1126 -      07:33 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held update
```

The thing is, this only happens when apts are executed from a script, if I execute exactly the same commands manually they never have this problem. Does the shell script run apt installs differently somehow?

In any case, what is the best way to run `apt` (or `yum` for that matter) installer from a shell script in a way that woudn't cause it to lock up?

Comment: Which user is running the script? Since you use `sudo` you must have a) a way to pass the password or b) a sudoers entry for the user to allow this command without password.

Comment: ^ Or you're running the script as root - in which case the `sudo` is irrelevant and meaningless

Comment: @roaima I do run the script as root, so you're right I don't need sodo's in the script itself

Answer (score 5):

You have to write `sudo apt-get install <package> -y` in the script.
Execute the script with `./setup.sh`

But of cause your user has to be a sudoer (sudo access).

Comment: The OP says that their script (in its entirely) is run as root using `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

It tells you (apt cannot get lock) that you need to run that bash script further in to post-install or wait for those process names not to be present.  You could be mean about it and kill the processes and delete the lockfile then apt-get update or just wait for them to finish.

Things that could make this fail - if you run apt-get install something as part of installing another package (don't do that, just use dependencies).

Comment: More likely apt is running from cron